# Symfony2, Sonata : Checkbox from entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata

I successfully displayed a list of checkbox from an entity "category"

- Cat1
- Cat2

But when i submit the form it returns an error :

> Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "SE\ApiBundle\Entity\Post#$postCategories", got "SE\ApiBundle\Entity\Category" instead.

So i guess i'm doing it the wrong way but can't find how to do.

It is similar to a ManyToMany relationship but i created an entity for my relation table :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post_category")
 */
class PostCategory
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="postCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_slug", referencedColumnName="slug")
     */
    private $category;

}
```

**Post :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 */
class Post
{

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PostCategory", mappedBy="post")
     **/
    private $postCategories;

 }
```

**Category :**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, name="slug")
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, name="name")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, name="class_icon")
     */
    private $classIcon;

}
```

**Sonata Admin :**

```
->add('postCategories', 'entity', 
    array(
        'class' => 'ApiBundle:Category',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true
    )
)
```

This is working with a ManyToMany relationship but i soon as i try with a relation table managed by my own entity it fails.

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I've had this problem too and I haven't found a way to get the Entity field with multiple=true working like this. It only works on real manyToMany relationships, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah so bad ... Well i'll use the ManyToMany relationship for now. It would be interesting to have a solution for that in case we want to add another property to PostCategory.